# W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date. Requires 8298000 but found 8107534

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-play-services, wear-os

As many other questions here on SO, I encounter a similar error message. Unlike other questions, this is regarding a hardware debugged device.

My gradle wear-build file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

Debuggin the app within the emulator works fine but as soon as I release the app and install it on my wearable, the connection between mobile and wear won't work. Debugging the wear over bluetooth (which is anything else but fast), shows this tiny line of debug information:

`W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8298000 but found 8107534`

I thought the gradle dependencies would pack the wearable-services together to the shipped apk (as there stands 'compile'), isn't that correct?

How can I bring the hardware watch to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Play Services is not going to be bundled with your app so what you are seeing is that your watch is using version 8.1 of the Play Services (which is installed on your watch) and you compiled your app with a higher version and that is not going to work; the version installed on your watch should always be bigger than or equal to the version you compiled your app with (same is true for your phone)

Comment: Ok - BUT - do you mean that these have to be specifically lowered to make it possible to say run an emulator? Right now Play Services are at 8.4.0 - i have my app and hw watch at this version - and they are working fine! But - the google wear emulator is at 8.3.0.0 (no idea if play services can be upgraded there or selected upon boot?) - so what now - to be able to test on emulator i have to manually.. specifically lower the versions? This sucks...

Comment: You may need to update your Android SDK since the latest emulators have Play Services 8.4 (I just verified that).

Comment: Mate - i've updated everything .. i am on the canary channel. That was my thought too but even after updating everything still crap.. i may need to reinstall everything :( My setup has not been wiped out since probably more than 4 years now...

Comment: To be clear, I tested that by setting my play services to 8.4 in an app and installing and running that on my emulator, so I assume if my emulator was running anything below 8.4, it would have complained.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow and see if a reinstall helps out. Both android phone app and companion wearable are at 8.4.0 - i've N-checked it. The wear app complains that the google play version is different with a tiny, tiny log message (which i missed at first). Then i checked in the wear emulator's Settings / About and really it says there Google Play Services: 8.3.1.... So i guess this must be an installation issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change this statement

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.8.99'
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to upgrade `Android Wear Smart Watch` on my emulator

First, I noticed my Google Play services on the emulator was out of date.
[image]

Go to play store, and click the top menu:
[image]

Find `Android Wear Smart Watch`, and update it.

[image]

After that, my Google play services is up-to-date.

Answer (score -1):

Google on your handset device "Download Google play services"
Will open your app store and then click on update.
That should do it.