# Please i need to know What is this version 8298000

Tags: service, admob, version, playback

after admob decision to stop ads in apps what works with google play service version less than sdk v7 
I need To Know What is This Version "8298000"
and please if you can tell me how i can know that ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your question has been answered in another question:

[W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date. Requires 8298000 but found 8107534](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597539/w-googleplayservicesutil-google-play-services-out-of-date-requires-8298000-but)

'Google Play Services is not going to be bundled with your app so what you are seeing is that your watch is using version 8.1 of the Play Services (which is installed on your watch) and you compiled your app with a higher version and that is not going to work; the version installed on your watch should always be bigger than or equal to the version you compiled your app with (same is true for your phone)'